# Help me with my friends code?

Tags: cipher

My friend has asked me to decrypt his code but I haven’t been given any clues and I was looking to see if any one could help me crack it. The code is: ╔á╔ª56╔áãÆ╔á╔ª56╔áãÆãÆ45╔áÓ½«2ãÆ45╔áÓ½«2╔ôÓ½«ÎÉ6ÔêéãÆ╔ôÓ½«ÎÉ6ÔêéãÆÎÉãÆ64ã¡Ó©úÎÉãÆ64ã¡Ó©úÓ©ú╔áãÆ4╔ªãÆÓ©ú╔áãÆ4╔ªãÆãÆÔêé4Ó½«╩ØÓ©úãÆÔêé4Ó½«╩ØÓ©úãÆ45╔áÓ½«2ãÆ45╔áÓ½«2ãÆÔêé4Ó½«╩ØÓ©úãÆÔêé4Ó½«╩ØÓ©úÓ©ú╔áãÆ4╔ªãÆÓ©ú╔áãÆ4╔ªãÆã¡5╔ª4ãÆÔêéã¡5╔ª4ãÆÔêé┬ÁÔêéãÆ╔▒45┬ÁÔêéãÆ╔▒45╔á╔ª56╔áãÆ╔á╔ª56╔áãÆ

Comment: Can you ask your friend if each symbol corresponds to a letter in the alphabet?

Answer (score 1):

### Partial answer: significant progress in analysing the text, but stuck

First, I noticed

> that each of the characters was in Code Page 850 (the character set used by DOS).
>
>  (Note: this isn't technically true: I had to normalize them, combining the "letter plus accent" characters into their single-character form.)

After a bit of time trying to decode as a cryptogram, I found an interesting structure to them:

> The text can be divided up into sections of 10-14 characters, each of which repeats twice. So it starts `╔á╔ª56╔áãÆ / ╔á╔ª56╔áãÆ / ãÆ45╔áÓ½«2 / ãÆ45╔áÓ½«2 / ╔ôÓ½«ÎÉ6ÔêéãÆ / ╔ôÓ½«ÎÉ6ÔêéãÆ`... (slashes added by me).

And even *more* structure:

> Many "chunks" of 2 or 3 characters in those lines were repeated. I marked all of them, and discovered an interesting piece of data coming out of there:
>   [image]
>  If we count each of the individual digits as a chunk as well, then:
>  - We have 16 different chunks total.
>  - Each line is exactly 6 chunks long.

This suggested something to me:

> these *could* be representing colors in hexadecimal. There are no commonly-recognized hex colors that have the form `__45__` (that I could find), so presumably the digits are encoded somehow too. (I'm still not sure how this encoding works, though -- I'll try to cryptogram it using lists of colors and see if I can break it that way.)
>
>  [image]
>  There are many different lists of hex colors, so this next part may be difficult to do without having figured out the encoding. Starting with the first color, it appears that there's only one hex color satisfying the `ablmac` pattern in the list of [extended web colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors). That would be Orchid, `DA70D6`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to give anything for some of the other colors: for example, there's no color fitting `__7D__` for the second line.

So, what next?

> Apart from the numbers, every single character in the message starts with a 1 bit (that is, it's not in ASCII range, but in the upper half of CP850.) This could be important to figuring out how the chunks are encoded. I didn't get anything out of various bit-manipulations on the results, though.
>
>  It's also possible that it's not colors being encoded at all, but something else that would make the repetition make sense. Each line being repeated twice *could* just be confirming the division into lines, but there could also be something else to it.